# How to rewrite interface for incoming packet using pf on macos?

Tags: macos, firewall

When my machine receives an incoming packet from a certain ip and port, I need to be able to rewrite that packet so that it appears to come from a different interface. As an example, if the packet appears on `en0` i want to change its interface so it appears on `en9` instead.

How would i do this using the `pf` firewall on macos?

Comment: From what I know, you can write your tun/tap interface, then forward all package to en9

Comment: @NghiaTran how to forward from the tun/tap ?